# Ignite 2.5: IgniteQueue.removeAll() throwing NPE

Tags: ignite

I am using IgniteQueue to store some POJOs in memory which are removed at a 15 minute interval after some processing. During the processing, elements are added and removed from the queue multiple times using removeAll() api.

Below is my queue configuration -

```java
@Override
public IgniteQueue<R> create(QueueName queueName, int capacity) {
    return ignite.queue(queueName.getQueueName(),  // Queue name.
             capacity,                             // Queue capacity. 0 for unbounded queue.
             getCollectionConfiguration());
}

private CollectionConfiguration getCollectionConfiguration() {
    CollectionConfiguration colCfg = new CollectionConfiguration();
    colCfg.setCollocated(true);
    colCfg.setCacheMode(REPLICATED);
    colCfg.setAtomicityMode(TRANSACTIONAL);

    return colCfg;
}
```

Recently, we have started receiving the below NPE -

```
2019-08-09 18:18:39,241 ERROR [Inbound-Main-Pool-13] [TransactionId: e5b5bfe3-5246-4d54-a4d6-acd550240e13 Request ID - 27845] [ APP=AladdinTransferAgentServer, ACTION=TA_SETTLEMENT, USER=tsgops ] SettlementWorkflowProcessor - Error while processing CLIENT settlement
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=LinkedList]
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:990)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheQueueAdapter$QueueIterator.remove(GridCacheQueueAdapter.java:687)
               at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(AbstractCollection.java:376)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheQueueProxy.removeAll(GridCacheQueueProxy.java:180)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.service.support.TAOrderSettlementIgniteQueueService.removeAll(TAOrderSettlementIgniteQueueService.java:63)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.service.support.TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.removeAllFromCurrentProcessing(TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.java:201)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.service.support.TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.lambda$removeAll$3(TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.java:100)
               at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.service.support.TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.removeAll(TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.java:100)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.service.support.TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.removeAll(TAOrderContextSettlementInputManager.java:90)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.processOrders(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:602)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.lambda$null$13(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:405)
               at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.lambda$null$14(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:368)
               at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.lambda$null$15(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:354)
               at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.lambda$null$16(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:345)
               at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.lambda$executeSettlementByClientSettleDateAndCurrency$17(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:337)
               at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.executeSettlementByClientSettleDateAndCurrency(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:330)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.executeSettlement(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:302)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.lambda$processSettlementFromQueue$6(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:282)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.locking.support.IgniteLockingService.execute(IgniteLockingService.java:39)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.locking.support.IgniteLockingService.execute(IgniteLockingService.java:68)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.processor.support.SettlementWorkflowProcessor.processSettlementFromQueue(SettlementWorkflowProcessor.java:281)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.facade.listener.support.TASettlementEventListener.listen(TASettlementEventListener.java:49)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.facade.listener.support.TASettlementEventListener.listen(TASettlementEventListener.java:19)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.common.listener.support.AbstractEventListener.onMessage(AbstractEventListener.java:44)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.common.listener.support.AbstractEventListener$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f1379f74.invoke(<generated>)
               at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.common.aop.aspect.MetricsTrackingAspect.trackMetrics(MetricsTrackingAspect.java:142)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.common.aop.aspect.MetricsTrackingAspect.logMetricsForListener(MetricsTrackingAspect.java:71)
               at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor657.invoke(Unknown Source)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.core.aop.aspect.LogContextAspect.logMetricsForListener(LogContextAspect.java:43)
               at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor596.invoke(Unknown Source)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
               at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
               at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
               at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
               at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
               at com.bfm.app.ta.settlement.facade.listener.support.TASettlementEventListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de3aafae.onMessage(<generated>)
               at com.bfm.beam.listeners.BeamListenerSupport.fireIncomingMessageToListener(BeamListenerSupport.java:140)
               at com.bfm.beam.listeners.BeamListenerSupport.fireIncomingMessage(BeamListenerSupport.java:103)
               at com.bfm.beam.listeners.BeamListenerSupport.fireOnIncomingMessage(BeamListenerSupport.java:84)
               at com.bfm.beam.SimpleBeamConnectionDriver$2.run(SimpleBeamConnectionDriver.java:326)
               at com.bfm.util.TransactionId$TransactionRunnable.run(TransactionId.java:116)
               at com.bfm.beam.executor.BeamWorkItem.run(BeamWorkItem.java:41)
               at com.bfm.beam.executor.BeamWorkerImpl.run(BeamWorkerImpl.java:109)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=LinkedList]
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridTransactionalCacheQueueImpl.removeItem(GridTransactionalCacheQueueImpl.java:211)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheQueueAdapter$QueueIterator.remove(GridCacheQueueAdapter.java:682)
               ... 67 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=LinkedList]
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.marshal(IgniteUtils.java:10050)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.marshal(IgniteUtils.java:10108)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.marshal(GridCacheUtils.java:780)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.marshal(GridCacheUtils.java:753)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxEntry.marshal(IgniteTxEntry.java:902)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMessage.marshalTx(GridCacheMessage.java:372)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedTxPrepareRequest.prepareMarshal(GridDistributedTxPrepareRequest.java:389)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onSend(GridCacheIoManager.java:1114)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1148)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearPessimisticTxPrepareFuture.preparePessimistic(GridNearPessimisticTxPrepareFuture.java:366)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearPessimisticTxPrepareFuture.prepare(GridNearPessimisticTxPrepareFuture.java:176)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.prepareNearTxLocal(GridNearTxLocal.java:3273)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.commitNearTxLocalAsync(GridNearTxLocal.java:3333)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.commit(GridNearTxLocal.java:3300)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridTransactionalCacheQueueImpl$4.call(GridTransactionalCacheQueueImpl.java:200)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.retryTopologySafe(GridCacheUtils.java:1479)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridTransactionalCacheQueueImpl.removeItem(GridTransactionalCacheQueueImpl.java:189)
               ... 68 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=LinkedList]
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:835)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:206)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.marshal(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:251)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.marshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:82)
               at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:58)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.marshal(IgniteUtils.java:10044)
               ... 84 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=T2]
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:835)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:206)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteCollection(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:764)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:707)
               ... 91 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=val1]
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:159)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:807)
               ... 97 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to marshal object with optimized marshaller: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheQueueAdapter$RemoveProcessor@6d82c986
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:186)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1160)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:682)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:155)
               ... 98 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize object: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheQueueAdapter$RemoveProcessor@6d82c986
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.marshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:206)
               at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:58)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.marshal(IgniteUtils.java:10044)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:179)
               ... 104 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheQueueAdapter$RemoveProcessor.writeExternal(GridCacheQueueAdapter.java:1021)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeExternalizable(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:317)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.write(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:814)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:240)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:158)
               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
               at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.marshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:201)
            ... 107 more
```

P.S. We don't have any class T2 with field val1

Also, the error is not reproducible locally nor on environment on demand. Also, it occurs only once and then every subsequent calls to remove from queue work fine.

Can someone please help with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Class T2 and val1 are Ignite classes and properties (part of its implementation of a tuple). This looks like a bug. I would suggest that the Ignite mailing lists might be a better place to talk about this. A short repro would also be useful.

Comment: Can you make a small reproducer a project for this issue? I will look on it, either suggest fix/workaround or raise an issue (maybe both).

Comment: The trouble is I am not able to reproduce it locally nor on demand on environment. Whenever it happened in the past, it happens only once in the whole transaction involving multiple addition and removal actions from the queue.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the objects that you put into this Queue? I believe that it's related to the object, that was put to it.

Comment: It is a regular pojo with getters, setters, hashcode and equals methods

Comment: Is there a chance that you have null as an element of the collection that you pass to the removeAll method? I see NullPointerException there

Comment: No null objects. We log the objects we are trying to remove.

Comment: Created a ticket in Ignite JIRA. Btw, have you tried to check it on Ignite 2.7.5, same issue?

Comment: Will give it a try. But not sure if I can recreate the error soon because it doesn't happen on demand. Another alternative that I am trying is to set atomicity to ATOMIC instead of TRANSACTIONAL since ignite queues don't follow the transactional way. And the error I am getting is in the transactional flow even only. So far haven't come across the error in test environment.

Comment: Wanted to add few more bits - I have a two instance server with replicated queues. This implies all the data is replicated to both nodes in the cluster. Now when I invoke queue.removeAll(), one node must be sending the primary list to the second node to remove from the backup. And this is where the serialization/deserialization occurs and it fails.